# Close Open TCP IP connection with .NET

Tags: .net, sockets, powershell, tcp

The .Net method `[Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections()` does exactly what it says; it gets all the active TCP connections. Anyone know a .Net class method that could be called to kill an open TCP connection?

Answer (score 3):

You can't close TCP sockets from .NET. Try using the free Tcpview tool instead. This can show open connections and will let you kill any open connection.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437

Answer (score 0):

As x0n indicates, to manage TCP connections programmatically you want the classes provided by [`System.Net.Sockets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) namespace. 
To disconnect from remote end points you want [BeginDisconnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.begindisconnect.aspx).

---

EDIT

However you will be able to disconnect end point connections only for the sockets that you have explicitely created with the `Socket` class. Therefore, you won't be able to disconnect the end points just gathering ip from the `NetworkInformation`.

Comment: Are you sure no way? I'm not expert about, but seems from Mircosoft documentation that is possible.

Comment: You cannot use any of the classes in the socket namespace to close any  TCP socket. Only those that you have created by yourself.

Comment: I see now. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I've updated the answer giving (hopefully) a more correct explanation. Thanks